# Property not found while object destructing typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using object deconstruct on a map, but I receive this error.  How do I handle the case that the object in the map is undefined?

```
const { amount } = data.get(id)
```

but I receive this error:

```
Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ amount: number; article: string; }>
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgJQKZwCbgDYE8A8A3vALYgCuYUSY5JARqgE4Dc8TUAlsNqktE05gA5mwC+APgBQMGAF4YxOGUrUYARgA07Ljz4wARHHrADMMSylTQkWEpVVz8+JaA). Is the type actually a union of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a check if `Map.get(k)` is `undefined`. The value returned from `.get(k)` is a union of whatever the value that gets set and `undefined`.

```
interface IClothing {
  amount: number;
  article: string;
}

const m: Map<number, IClothing> = new Map()
m.set(1, { amount: 10, article: 'shirt' })

const p1 = m.get(1)
const { amount } = p1 !== undefined ? p1 : {amount: 0};
```

So in my example, `m.get(1)` is a union of `IClothing` and `undefined` and a check should be done to ensure its not.